# Cleave change string with comma to string without comma after sending a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

js component for number filed in my form on my site, this components show on the interface as number with commas when user type like that "100,000". how i can make it happen, that when user send the form it will save it as string without a commas like that "100000"?

Is there some function that can help me to that right?

this is the documentation...

https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js/blob/master/doc/options.md#onvaluechanged

```
 <Cleave
        placeholder={placeholder}
        options={{
          numeral: true,
          numeralDecimalScale: 4,
        }}
        
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
         id={id}
        className="form-control"
      />
```

Comment: I assume `<form onSubmit={doSomething}>` where doSomething sets the value to a js number before sending

Answer (score 0):

an ugly but quick method, if 100.000 is int then start by transforming it into a string then use `replace()`.

```js
let t = 100.000
const p = t.toString().replace('.', '') //p = '100000'
```